# Burning smell from usb port after connecting + and - of it (laptop)

Tags: laptop, usb, motherboard, burning, physical-damage

I was testing my android phone charging cable on my laptop USB port (it has only 2 wires + and - as it is only for charging).

then I smell a burning plastic smell coming out of the USB port.

I found that the 2 wires (+ and -) of the cable were connected which caused the problem.

The problem is that one electric component of the motherboard gone damaged.

here is the image of it :

[image]

the laptop still works, but it hangs and freezes when connecting my (Alfa network RTL8187) to that USB port

I want to know if that component can be replaced without replacing the whole motherboard and if so, how much will that cost?

my laptop model is Fujitsu Lifebook a series AH531

Comment: You fried the port.  Why are you using it? The wire created a short to ground

Comment: You shorted it & let out the [Magic Smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke). Next stop, repair shop.

Comment: @Ramhound .. can it be repaired without replacing the whole motherboard?

Comment: If you asked an electrician, they'd probably say it's cheaper to replace.  An electrician once told me that in the old days they'd repair televisions properly, and diagnose issues. Since then they just swap boards like monkeys.    And maybe since then they just replace the whole thing!

Comment: You'd need a schematic which details the component, then you need to find one. Most discrete I2C devices like that come on a roll of 100+. You then need to be half decent at soldering to remove the old chip and replace it with a new one. It's not a 5 minute job. You also can't be sure other components aren't also damaged.

Comment: @ibrahem - I would need to see the board in front of me to determine that.  Based on the age of the device it might not be worth the amount of money, a trained repair technician would charge to repair the board, let alone the need to find a replacement part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask this question, then you're not knowledgeable enough to fix this by yourself. Not to mention you don't have the necessary tools.

Try to find a repair shop that does component level repair. They may be able to swap this component for a new one. The best case scenario is that this will be possible and sufficient.

What can go wrong:

- It may not be possible to identify the component
- Some other components may be damaged too, possibly more expensive ones
- The component may be fused with the motherboard an removing it may cause further damage
- Incompetent technician can make things worse